# Cannot find module windows 10 from subdirectory

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, path

I am trying to run a node.js script from a walkthrough I found online however I am gettings errors early on. 
(Link to walkthrough I am trying to go through) https://www.education-ecosystem.com/elliottminns/l5DN4-how-to-create-a-cryptocurrency-trading-bot-in-nodejs/q6knD-how-to-create-a-cryptocurrency-trading-bot-in-no-7/

When I run the code with Node.js in windows 10 its give me an error where it can't find the other modules or other .js files in the subdirectory.

I know this is something probably super simple but when I look around, I think I getting the wrong information.

I use Brackets to look at the project folders and .js files, and I use cmd with node or node.js to run the index.js file.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens when you require `./app`? Btw, I think you need `./src/app`

Comment: You are totally correct! I needed ./src/app because that is where the relative path in relation to the main index.js file was. (I was being stupid and didn't realize there was another subdirectory inbetween /app and the main root of the relative path. lol)

I am still coming across different errors but appreciate that people are will to help me on the basics and user error problems. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
const app = require("app");
```

will make Node attempt to load a module called `app` from the `node_modules` folder.

Obviously, this is not what you want – instead, you need to load a file which is located *relative* to the current file. To specify a relative load path, use this:

```
const app = require("./app");
```

Node will then look for a file or directory called `app`. If it's a directory, it will load `index.js` from it.

An excerpt from [this article](https://adrianmejia.com/getting-started-with-node-js-modules-require-exports-imports-npm-and-beyond):

> The require function will look for files in the following order:
>
> - Built-in core Node.js modules (like `fs`)
> - NPM Modules. It will look in the `node_modules` folder
> - Local Modules. If the module name has a `./`, `/` or `../`, it will look for the directory/file in the given path.

Comment: Thank you for the article, it confirmed some things I thought about and other things I had no clue of. This helped me a lot!!